# Pytorch DataLoader - working with individual batches

Tags: python, lstm, pytorch

I am building an LSTM for part-of-speech tagging, and am currently using [this LSTM](https://github.com/jiangqy/LSTM-Classification-Pytorch/blob/master/main.py) as reference to understand how to use the Pytorch DataLoader. However, I'm confused as to how to work with individual batches (official Pytorch documentation doesn't shed any light for me). More specifically I need to pad my sentences so that all the sentences *in the same batch* are of the same length (different batches can have different lengths).

My code currently looks like:

```
train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

# other stuff...

for epoch in range(0, EPOCH_COUNT):
    for iter, sentence in enumerate(train_loader):
        model.zero_grad()
        model.hidden = model.init_hidden()
        sentence_in = prep_sentence(sentence, word_to_ix)
        targets = prep_tags(tags, tag_to_ix)
        # do forward pass and then backprop
```

Since I'm enumerating train_loader and iterating through each sentence, it's not clear to me how/at what point I can get the max sentence length of a single batch and then run my add_padding() function.

Comment: you should look at the collate function  you supply to the data loader